# minor bug in comment code tags

Tags: bug, comments, markdown, code-formatting

I seem to have found a minor bug in the formatting of code within comments.  Code that ends in a `=` followed by a space "consumes" any space after it.  I realize that multiple spaces are automatically removed but in this case I don't think it works quite as intended.  The comment:

```
code `test = ` tag
```

Formats as:

[image]

I think it should format as it would within a post: code `test =` tag
(With a space between the light gray code area and the word tag.)

Comment: Example: code `test = ` tag