# What happened to the tag badge progress counts?

Tags: bug, profile-page, badge-progress

So it looks like there was a recent change or regression that isn't showing the score/answer counts for the tag tracking.

What happened to the counts?  Please add it back, or at least explain why it needed to be removed.  The counts are shown for regular non-tag badges...

[image: no more counts]

This makes the tag selection page mostly useless now, especially with the different scaling for the different badge levels.

[image: now mostly useless]

Comment: @Catija well, it means people really care about it... :)

Comment: Yup, I just duplicated myself, Jeff.

Comment: Self duplication? True Wizard, @Mr.Wizard ;)

Comment: @Shadow Self Closure, too. :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Meh, it doesn't help when search isn't yielding any results, unless you are constantly watching meta like a hawk and know what was asked recently.

Comment: p.s. do others see the bug I reported here?: [(256931)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256931/)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I see it but it's just too minor - there's already a space, so why add another space? Anyway, funny to have two wizards in one place.... :P